# return a list filtered by vowel count in python

Tags: python, list

return a list which has only words from input list that contain atleast count vowels

```
    def filter_by_vowel_count(input, count):
        result = []
        for word in input:
           if sum(p in 'aeiou' for p in word) == count:
            result.append(word)
        return result
      pass

    assert  [] == filter_by_vowel_count(["engine", "hello", "cat", "dog", "why"], 5)
    assert  ["engine"] == filter_by_vowel_count(["engine", "hello", "cat", "dog", "why"], 3)
    assert  ["hello", "engine"] == filter_by_vowel_count(["hello", "engine", "cat", "dog", "why"], 2)
    assert  ["hello", "engine", "dog", "cat"] == filter_by_vowel_count(["hello", "engine", "dog", "cat", "why"], 1)
    # even capital vowels are vowels :)
    assert  ["HELLO", "ENGINE", "dog", "cat"] == filter_by_vowel_count(["HELLO", "ENGINE", "dog", "cat", "why"], 1)
    assert  ["HELLO", "ENGINE", "dog", "cat", "why"] == filter_by_vowel_count(["HELLO", "ENGINE", "dog", "cat", "why"], 0)
```

can anyone help me to write the function to satisfy above conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're a beginner, I think its best to begin with normal loops and simple constructs instead of more complex library tools.

So, this is my version of your function:

```
def filter_by_vowel_count(inp, count):  # We changed input to inp as input is a special function in Python

    ret = []  # The list to return
    for word in inp:
        total = 0  # The total nubmer of vowels
        for letter in word:
            if letter in 'aeiouAEIOU':  # Note that some letters might be in capital
                total += 1
        if total >= count:
            ret.append(word)
    return ret
```

Your problem was using the `==` where you should have use `>=`. Here is a better version using a list comprehension:

```
def filter_by_vowel_count(inp, count):

    return [word for word in inp if sum(1 for p in word if p in 'aeiouAEIOU') >= count]
```

This is pretty much your algorithm, but in one line. You can learn more about them [here](http://carlgroner.me/Python/2011/11/09/An-Introduction-to-List-Comprehensions-in-Python.html).

Comment: @FredrikPihl Happy to oblige :)